# Is there a video size limitation for local files in the Google Cloud Video Intelligence API?

Tags: video-intelligence-api

I am thinking about integrating the Google Video Intelligence API for automatic labeling of my videos. If possible I do not want to use Google Cloud Storage for this issue. 
Is there a limitation of video file size when making requests for locally stored files?

I already found the page metioning the limit size of 10GB (see https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/quotas). Yet, I am wondering if this holds for local files or if there is a difference like e.g. in the Google Speech-to-Text API where longer audio durations are possible if the file is stored on Cloud Storage (see https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas).